# Cron not executing

Tags: scripts, cron

I have set crontab to execute a script in my home directory. This is the line:

```
0 * * * * ~/minds.sh # JOB_ID_1
```

The script itself has been placed inside `/etc/cron.daily/` and it still is not executing. It has execute permissions and the ownership of the script is correct, first case the home user owns the script and in the second case root.

It is supposed to run every hour. I cant figure out what is going on and why it is not working. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

To update I have edited the crontab and it is now `0 * * * * /home/user/minds # JOB_ID_1`. I have remove the .sh extension and the scrip works. Now I just have to wait for it to see if it will work. Will report back in an hour.

UPDATE2:

The crontab and /etc/cron.daily/ are not executing at all.

Comment: did you check manually to execute a sh file and find is it works fine or not?

Comment: `cron` doesn't understand `~/` use an absolute path instead `/home/user/...`

Comment: I have updated the question. Will report back in an hour.

Comment: @steeldriver Nothing is executing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of reading this appears to work. [Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=185993) is the relevant article:

```
0 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/user/minds >log 2>&1 # JOB_ID_1
```